# Adjusting the horizontal alignment of labels of nested numbering lists

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem, exam, nesting

In the following example I have succeeded aligning the first level of numbering both internal numbering of exam document class and numbering of enumitem  package exactly after the left margin. I would like to configure the alignment of both lists environments (internal of exam document class and enumitem) so the left edge of the label of the next level nested numbering list to be perfectly aligned with the first letter of TEXT of the previous level of numbering. I would like to achieve that using not absolute numbers but internal lengths of latex so the result to be the same in case I change the geometry of my document. Is it possible?

the code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={160mm,257mm},left=25mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[1]{left=\hoffset}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\roman*)}
\renewcommand\subpartlabel{(\thesubpart)}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}}
\begin{document}
\noindent Next list uses internal lists of exam document class:

    \begin{questions}
        \question \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[line width=0.5pt](0,0.5) -- (0,-10);This is a text which is longer than a single line just to check the indentation of this question in respect to the left margin.
            \begin{parts}
                \part \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[line width=0.5pt](0,0.5) -- (0,-10);The left edge of the label of this part I would like to be exactly inline with the first letters of text of the higher level numbering which are the letters T and q above
            \end{parts}
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart The left edge of this subpart I would like to be inline (aligned) exactly with te first letter of the previous level of enumeration. 
                \end{subparts}
    \end{questions}

\noindent Next list uses enumitem package:

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is the first level of numbering
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Next level numbering list
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item Next Next numbering list
                    \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is something like the following you want?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{exam}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[a4paper, total={160mm,257mm},left=25mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[1]{left=\hoffset}
    \setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\roman*)}
    \renewcommand\subpartlabel{(\thesubpart)}
    \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent Next list uses enumitem package:

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is the first level of numbering
                \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
                    \item Next level numbering list
                        \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
                            \item Next Next numbering list
                        \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I want concerning enumitem package and thanks for that!  What can I do to achieve this with the internal list numbering system of exam document class (questions, parts, subparts etc)? I think this will not work with exam document class as it uses a different system for creating the nested lists.

Comment: @Miltod P.: unfortunately, I don't use personally the exam package, so I have no idea *a priori*,   but I'll try to examine the code this evening.

Comment: How can I extend this procedure for at least two more listing levels?

Comment: I think you continue to use the parameter `wide=0pt`, meaning there is no label indent w.r.t. the margin (in a nested enumerate, the new margin is where the item text starts).

Comment: Yes but every previous level needs the option `leftmargin=*`

Comment: I didn't test, but probably you're right. You also might, with `enumitem` , define an own enumerate environment and set these keys globally  in the preamble.